# Como validar lo que retorna el getEventText(event) Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

estoy trabajando con accesibilidad, escuchando esos eventos. Estoy validando así.

```
if ("la administración del dispositivo" == getEventText(event) ){
                        Metodo(); 
                    }
```

Se supone que getEventText(event) me devuelve un texto, y estoy validando que si el texto es igual a ese debe ejecutar el metodo, pero no sucede nada.
 En cambio si valido por ejemplo

```
if(event.getPackageName().toString().equals("com.android.settings")){

    Si ejecuta.

    }
```

Comment: y como tienes tu código del método getEventText(event)???

Answer (score 2):

El texto obtenido mediante getEventText() no esta relacionado con el paquete, esta relacionado a un evento de interacción con la aplicación.

```
private String getEventText(AccessibilityEvent event) {

    if (event.getText() == "TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED"){
         // evento vista click.
         return "TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED";
           } else if( event.getText() == "TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED"){
          // evento enfoque vista.
          return "TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED";
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

No se con `getEventText(event)` pero si event.getText() funciona pero no todas las aplicaciones te dan el texto que deseas,

1. Prueba Logear el resultado
2. Para comprobar strings en Java no se debe usar `str1 == str2` sino `str1.equals(str2)`
3. El texto completo no me parece que sea ese "la administración del dispositivo" si no una parte asi que usa la funcion contains

Prueba algo asi:

```
if(event.getPackageName().toString().equals("com.android.settings o la app que quieres capturar")){
    String text = event.getText().toString();
Log.d("AppEjemplo",text);
    if (text.contains("la administración del dispositivo")  ){
                            Metodo(); 
}
}
```

Tambien puedes filtrar por clases
En esta por ahora si funciona el metodo event.getText()

```
if (event.getClassName().equals("android.app.AlertDialog")) {...
```

Para otras aplicaciones tienes que interar en los controles para obtener el texto de cada componente Ej:

```
AccessibilityRecordCompat record = AccessibilityEventCompat.asRecord(event);
final AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat source = record.getSource();
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
private void logControls(AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat source, StringBuilder sb) {
        if (source != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < source.getChildCount(); i++) {
                final AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat currentSource = source.getChild(i);
                if(currentSource.getClassName().equals("android.widget.TextView")){
                    sb.append(currentSource.getText()+" ");
                }else if(currentSource.getClassName().equals("android.widget.EditText")){
                    mediatekEditText=currentSource;
                }
                logControls(currentSource, sb);
            }
        }
    }
```